# how to separate stuff I want from what I don't in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have to apply transformations on code C++ code, but not comments or preprocessor statements.  It's the preprocessor statements that I'm having trouble with.  Basically, I want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $doubleQuotedString = q{"(?>[^"\\\\]++|\\\\{2}|\\\\(?s).)*+"};
my $singleQuotedString = q{'(?>[^'\\\\]++|\\\\{2}|\\\\(?s).)*+'};
my ($rest, $code, $stuffToIgnore) = ("");
open(my $inputFH, "<:raw:crlf", $file) or die "can't open $file for reading. $!";
open(my $outputFH, ">:raw:crlf", "$file.out") or die "can't open $file.out for writing. $!";
my $counter = 0;
while (<$inputFH>)
{
        $_ = "$rest$_";
        do
        {
                ($code, $stuffToIgnore, $rest) = m(
                        ((?:
                                 $doubleQuotedString                 # found a string
                                |$singleQuotedString                 # found a string
                                |(?:[^/]++|/[^*/])                   # found something not a string, comment or preprocessor statement
                         )*+
                        )
                        ((?:
                                ^\s*+#.*$ |                          # preprocessor statement
                                \s*+//.*$ |                          # line comment
                                \s*+/\*(?:[^*]++|\*(?!/))*+\*/       # block comment
                         )*+
                        )
                        ((?s).*)                                     # rest
                 )xm;
                 ++$counter;
                 goto BLOCK_READ if $stuffToIgnore ne "" or eof($inputFH);
        } while ($_ .= <$inputFH>);
        BLOCK_READ:
        defined $code or die "Unterminated block.";

        # do transformation on $code

        print "CODE: >>$code<<\nIGNORE: >>$stuffToIgnore<<\n";
        print $outputFH "$code$stuffToIgnore";
}
```

My problem is the one commented as `# found something not a string, comment or preprocessor statement`.  Commenting out the line `# preprocessor statement` make it work for, but it will consider preprocessor statements as code to apply the transformation on.

How can I change the first part of the regex to fail on a preprocessor statement?  Or maybe you have another way of doing this?

**EDIT**

I finished the answer given @sln's help.  I'm posting it here as a reference at to how I accomplished what I was attempting to do while also leaving in some debugging stuff for those who are interested.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0];

my $debug = 1;

my ($rest, $code, $ignore) = ("");
my $lineNumber = 1;
my $topLineOfBlock;

open(my $inputFH, "<:raw:crlf", $file) or die "can't open $file for reading. $!";
open(my $outputFH, ">:raw:crlf", "$file.out") or die "can't open $file.out for writing. $!";

my $complete = 1; # NOTE: These 2 must be declared in the base scope of the package.
my $lineOffset;   #       See https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=120554 for details.

while ($_ = <$inputFH>, !eof($inputFH) or length($rest) != 0)
{
  $topLineOfBlock = $lineNumber;
  print "Read line $lineNumber\n" if $debug;
  if (defined $_)
  {
    $_ = "$rest$_";
  }
  else
  {
    $_ = $rest;
  }
  my $loopAgain;
  do
  {
    if (/\\$/)  # if line ends with '\' read and append in next line
    {
      $complete = 0;
    }
    elsif (eof($inputFH) or /;\s*+$/) # if eof or line does end in a ';', break it up.
    # otherwise read and append in next line.
    {
      print "INPUT: '$_'\n" if $debug;
      use re 'eval';
      m%
          (?{print "STRING: '${^POSTMATCH}'\n" if $debug})
          (?{$lineOffset = 0})
          # ROUTINES
            (?!) # Ignore this section for matching

          # DEBUG ROUTINES
          # Call them using (?N) where N is the corrisponding number.
            ((?{print  "1]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print  "2]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print  "3]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print  "4]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print  "5]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print  "6]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print  "7]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print  "8]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print  "9]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print "10]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print "11]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print "12]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print "13]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print "14]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print "15]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print "16]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print "17]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print "18]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))
            ((?{print "19]'${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug}))

          # SUBROUTINES
            # States that code read in is in an incomplete state.
            (?<INCOMPLETE>(?{print "INCOMPLETE: '${^MATCH}'\n" if $debug; $complete = 0;}))

            # States that code read in is in a completed state.
            (?<COMPLETE>  (?{print "COMPLETE: '${^MATCH}'\n"   if $debug; $complete = 1;}))

            # Matches against one character that has been escaped including EOL.
            # If a quoted EOL found, mark match as incomplete.
            (?<ESCAPED_CHAR>
              \\
              (?:
                (?&EOL)       (?&INCOMPLETE)
                | (?s).
              )
            )

            # Matches against a single quoted string excluding EOL.
            (?<SINGLE_QUOTED_STRING>
              \'(?&INCOMPLETE)             # Escaped quotes due to a syntax highlighting bug in SO
              (?:
                  [^\'\\\\n]++             # Escaped quotes due to a syntax highlighting bug in SO
                | (?&ESCAPED_CHAR)
              )*+
              \'(?&COMPLETE)               # Escaped quotes due to a syntax highlighting bug in SO
            )

            # Matches against a double quoted string excluding EOL.
            (?<DOUBLE_QUOTED_STRING>
              \"(?&INCOMPLETE)             # Escaped quotes due to a syntax highlighting bug in SO
              (?:
                  [^\"\\\n]++              # Escaped quotes due to a syntax highlighting bug in SO
                | (?&ESCAPED_CHAR)
              )*+
              \"(?&COMPLETE)               # Escaped quotes due to a syntax highlighting bug in SO
            )

            # matches strings intermingled with other chars excluding EOL.
            (?<STRINGS_WITH_CHARS>
              (?:
              #   (?&NON_ESCAPED_CHARS)
                  [^\\\n\"\']++             # Escaped quotes due to a syntax highlighting bug in SO
                | (?&DOUBLE_QUOTED_STRING)
                | (?&SINGLE_QUOTED_STRING)
                | (?&ESCAPED_CHAR)
              )*+
            )

            # Matches against non escaped characters excluding EOL.
            (?<NON_ESCAPED_CHARS> [^\\\n]++)

            # Matches all non escaped chars and escaped chars.
            # upto but not including the EOL unless it's escaped.
            (?<CHARS> (?:(?&NON_ESCAPED_CHARS)|(?&ESCAPED_CHAR))*+)

            # Matches EOL (end of line) or EOS (end of string) and states it is in a complete state.
            (?<EOL_OR_EOS> (?&EOL) | $     (?&COMPLETE))

            # Matches on EOL and increments $lineOffset if matched.
            # When using this, make sure you don't allow backtracking over this call.
            (?<EOL> \n(?{++$lineOffset}))

          | # ACTUAL SEARCH
          (?<ignore>
            (?:
                (?&EOL)? ^ [^\S\n]*+ \# (?&STRINGS_WITH_CHARS) (?&EOL_OR_EOS) # preprocessor statement
              # Escaping slashes due to a syntax highlighting bug in SO
              | \s*+ \/\/ (?&CHARS) (?&EOL_OR_EOS)    # line comment
              | \s*+ \/\* (?&INCOMPLETE)      # block comment
                (?:
                    [^*]++
                  | \* (?!\/)
                )*+
                \*\/ (?&COMPLETE)             # block comment completed
            )*+
          )
          (?(?{$complete}) # completed parse of all ignored stuff?  Then read code stuff.
            (?<code>
              (?:
                (?!^[^\S\n]*+\#)               # do not match on a preprocessor statement
                (?:
                    (?&DOUBLE_QUOTED_STRING)   # found a string
                  | (?&SINGLE_QUOTED_STRING)   # found a string
                  | (?: [^\'\"/\n]++ | /[^*/\n]) # found something not a string or comment or newline
                                               # Escaped quotes due to a syntax highlighting bug in SO
                  | (?&EOL)                    # newline
                )
              )*+
            )
            (?<rest>
              (?s).*                         # match to the end of the string
            )
          ) # if not completed, read in more stuff and do parse over again.
      %xmp;
      ($code, $ignore, $rest) = ($+{'code'}, $+{'ignore'}, $+{'rest'});
      print "**COMPLETE = $complete\n" if $debug;
      goto BLOCK_READ_COMPLETE if $complete or eof($inputFH);
    }
    # read in more data to allow for a complete parse
    ++$lineNumber;
    print "Reading line $lineNumber\n" if $debug;

    my $newStuff = <$inputFH>;
    if (defined $newStuff)
    {
      $_ .= $newStuff;
      $loopAgain = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      $loopAgain = 0;
    }
  } while ($loopAgain);
  BLOCK_READ_COMPLETE:
  $complete or die "Something wasn't terminated at line ". ($topLineOfBlock+$lineOffset) ." of file '$file'.\n";

  # do transformation on $code

  print "CODE: >>$code<<\nIGNORE: >>$ignore<<\nREST: >>$rest<<\n" if $debug;
  print $outputFH "$ignore$code";
}
```

To see a working demo, see [here](http://ideone.com/mDN2kj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.
Some questions. Are you accumulating and processing more than 1 line at a time?

If not, I don't see any provisions for block comments that extend over multiple lines.
Also, block comments consume line comments, and I don't see any provisions for line comment continuation.

**Edit - 5** 
@Adrian - I punched up a version that works for me. The Perl code and output are below.
Let me know if this does the trick.
Note that a added line continuation code for `#`Preprocessor as well as `//`Line comments
and it tests out very nice.

```
 my $doubleQuotedString = q{"(?>[^"\\\\]++|\\\\{2}|\\\\(?s).)*+"};
 my $singleQuotedString = q{'(?>[^'\\\\]++|\\\\{2}|\\\\(?s).)*+'};

 my ($rest, $code, $stuffToIgnore) = ("");

 my $counter = 0;


 while (<DATA>)
 {
         $_ = "$rest$_";
         do
         {
                 ($code, $stuffToIgnore, $rest) = m~

                       (                              # (1), Code
                            (?:
                                 (?! ^ [^\S\n]* \# )            #  Not a preprocessor statement
                                 (?:
                                      $ doubleQuotedString           # found a string
                                   |  $ singleQuotedString           # found a string
                                   |  (?: [^/\n]++ | / [^*/\n] )     # found something not a string or comment or newline
                                   |  \n                             # newline
                                 )
                            )*+
                       )

                       (                              # (2), Ignore
                            (?:
                                 \s*+ ^ [^\S\n]* \#             # '#' Preprocessor statement with Continuation logic
                                 (?:
                                      [^\\]                          # any Non-Continuation character ^\
                                   |  \\ \n?                         # Or,  any Continuation character followed by optional newline
                                 )*?
                                 (?<! \\ )
                                 \n
                              |
                                 \s*+ /\*                       # '/**_**/' Block comment
                                 (?:
                                      [^*]++
                                   |  \*
                                      (?! / )
                                 )*+
                                 \*/
                              |
                                 \s*+ //                        # '//' Line comment, with Continuation logic
                                 (?:
                                      [^\\]
                                   |  \\ \n?

                                 )*?
                                 (?<! \\ )
                                 \n
                            )*+
                       )

                       (                              # (3), Rest
                            (?s)
                            .*
                       )
                  ~xm;

                  ++$counter;
                  goto BLOCK_READ if $stuffToIgnore ne "" or eof(DATA);

         } while ($_ .= <DATA>);

         BLOCK_READ:
         defined $code or die "Unterminated block.";

         # do transformation on $code

         print "CODE:   >>$code<<\nIGNORE: >>$stuffToIgnore<<\n---------------------------------------\n";
 }


 __DATA__

 # hello \
 there
 # how
 # are
 #you

 #pragma once

 #include "EditState.h"
 #include "MyDoc.h"

 // InputEdit

 class CInputEdit : public CEdit
 {
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CInputEdit)

 public:
    CInputEdit();
    virtual ~CInputEdit();

 // Attributes
 protected:

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    BOOL m_bTrackingMenu;

 };
```

Output

```
 CODE:   >>
 <<
 IGNORE: >># hello \
 there
 <<
 ---------------------------------------
 CODE:   >><<
 IGNORE: >># how
 <<
 ---------------------------------------
 CODE:   >><<
 IGNORE: >># are
 <<
 ---------------------------------------
 CODE:   >><<
 IGNORE: >>#you
 <<
 ---------------------------------------
 CODE:   >>
 <<
 IGNORE: >>#pragma once
 <<
 ---------------------------------------
 CODE:   >>
 <<
 IGNORE: >>#include "EditState.h"
 <<
 ---------------------------------------
 CODE:   >><<
 IGNORE: >>#include "MyDoc.h"
 <<
 ---------------------------------------
 CODE:   >>
 <<
 IGNORE: >>// InputEdit
 <<
 ---------------------------------------
 CODE:   >>
 class CInputEdit : public CEdit
 {
         DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CInputEdit)

 public:
         CInputEdit();
         virtual ~CInputEdit();

 <<
 IGNORE: >>// Attributes
 <<
 ---------------------------------------
 CODE:   >>protected:

         DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

         BOOL m_bTrackingMenu;

 };

 <<
 IGNORE: >><<
 ---------------------------------------
```

Comment: Yes, I'm accumulating more than one line of code to transform at a time.  That's what the `do/while` loop is for.  As for multiline block comments, they are provided for via the `# block comment` section.  This would also consume any line comments embedded in the block comment.  You're right about the line comment continuation.  Also applies to preprocessor continuation too.

Comment: **Edit2:** this will not work.  the `# found something not ...` will capture a preprocessor statement and that's the main problem.  **Edit:** Thanks for your help, but that is not really that concerning, I have that under control.

Comment: FYI, `[^\\]` matches `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: I think that the -ve assertion might hold some promise though.

Comment: @Adrian - See **Edit3** . If you expect preprocessor in the middle of your text stream, but be the first statement on a line, this will exclude it from Grp1 ccapture. And let it be captured in Grp2. And, thanks for the FYI, but in this context, `[^\\]` has no relavence to `\n` unless its `\\ \n`

Comment: Ah, Missed the `*?` at the end there.

Comment: Well, given the simple test file [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JyZnfJx3), it doesn't work.

Comment: @Adrian - Ok, I added a working example; **Edit5**. Some tweeks were needed. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Your help has been invaluable @sln.  Thank you.  I've taken some of your stuff and have incorporated it into my work.  I've not tested your current incarnation, but I'm going to give you the answer anyway.  If you want to see what I actually did, see the main question.

Comment: Some things I added was globing ignored stuff together, removing unnecessary searches, adding 'functions' to make the code easier to read and debugging code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find success by first breaking up the complexity of your regex into discrete pieces. Just pulling the different possible matches into separate `if` blocks will make a big difference for readability.

You should also be able to leverage the fact that there are a small number of preprocessor directives.

Comment: I don't see how that would make it easier to read, or how I would do it as easily in that way.